# Can a wireless connection have the same connect as an ethernet cable

Tags: wireless-networking, ipad

I'm trying to screenmirror my ipad to my pc via APowersoft, but then a problem arises you see my pc can only be connected to the internet by an ethernet cable and for an ipad via wifi. I've tried looking online for how it could be possible but couldn't find out anything about it

I'm trying to connect my ipad to the wifi to connect / screen mirror the ipad to my pc which has an ethernet cable or if there is any diffrent software that isn't anydesk/teamviewer like as I find it inconvient.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a Wi-Fi device and a wired Ethernet device can be connected into the same LAN together. This exactly what an "Access Point" (AP) does; it acts as a **point** (place) where Wi-Fi devices can get **access** to some kind of underlying network, most commonly an Ethernet LAN. Note that all "wireless routers" are APs, and most of them transparently bridge traffic between wireless device and the LAN ports, making your Wireless LAN (WLAN) and your wired Ethernet LAN all one big hybrid wired+wireless LAN.

Just plug your PC into a LAN port of your wireless router, and have your iPad join the wireless network created by the router, and you should be able to screen mirror between the two as if they were directly connected via an Ethernet cable.

If you already tried that and it isn't working, then your router may be set up to keep wireless and wired LAN traffic separate. You can usually change that in your router's settings.

Comment: Yes I have set it up to have seperate traffics for security reasons

Comment: @Explorer404 Well I guess you have your answer then. If you knew you'd blocked your Wi-Fi devices from talking to your Ethernet devices, you shouldn't be surprised when your Wi-Fi iPad can't screen share with your Ethernet PC.